# How to change my vote on a tag synonym if it is already removed?

Tags: support, tag-synonyms

I accidentally downvoted the `log4net` synonym `log4netconfiguration` and it was removed automatically. I do not quite understand how this happend because before I voted the score was on zero. In any case, I want to change my vote but do not see how do this. I could of course add the synonym again, but that would seem wrong, as someone else thought of this synonym... can this be fixed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once the synonym has been removed because it got a score of −2, there isn't anything you can do to undo the down-vote you gave to the synonym. All you can do is to re-add it to tag.
Not even moderators can do something in such cases.